# Running mutation on PostMan returns "Method not allowed"

Tags: android, graphql, postman, web-api-testing

I want to run a mutation using Postman, and I am getting

> Method not allowed.

When I run it on the GraphQl Playground, It works completely fine

[image]

Whereas If I run it on Postman I can't get it to work.

[image]

Here are the raw logs from Postman.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're sending your request to `/graphiql`, which is presumably the path to your GraphiQL interface, not your API. You should use `/graphql` or whatever you've configured on your web server.